# Node.js Multiple Webapps

Tags: node.js, apache, reactjs, tomcat

I am currently in testing phase, going through all webserver options. I was wondering if it was possible to run a directory of webapps on the same port on node.js (basically to have multiple versions of my app with a config calling different apis). In the same way one can have a version Directory in Apache or Tomcat.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible. Try to explain in more details what you're trying to achieve. I have no idea what *version Directory in Apache or Tomcat* is.

Comment: I figured it out thank you though, what I meant is a directory full of different versions of your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] I figured it out, what I did was create a folder as a directory and added all the builds to it and called `http-server` in the folder containing the builds

Comment: You can accept an answer to let us know you have solved your problem. It's that check mark over to the side.